# Is it possible to set TFS checkin permissions on a directory in a project?

Tags: entity-framework, tfs, permissions

To prevent Entity Framework migrations clashing, we have nominated a team member to carry out all explicit migrations and check them into the solution.

I can't find anything at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252587(v=vs.110).aspx

Is it possible to set TFS permissions to only allow a specific team member write access to add/edit files under a specific directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes this can be done but you will most likely have to disable the group inheiritance on the Folder and add the user specifically, if other team members need read access you will need to assign the appropriate group.

In Visual Studio select the folder you want to change permission on:

Right Click --->Select Security ---> Uncheck Inherit permission for the groups you want to remove --> Select Remove. Repeat as needed

Then select radio button - Windows User or Group --> Find User --> Check The Permissions you want to Assign ---> Click Add button. Repeat as needed

You can also set up TFS Email Alerts on the folder for a Team Lead to monitor any activity on the folder.